Renderer behavior in Next.js AppRouter
I'm using react-notion-x with next.js to render a blog post on Notion.
Since I switch to Next.js with AppRouter with the "use client", I'm unable to render the customer image component.
The image on browser use the original url (which is expired in 2 hours) instead of fetch data to Cloudinary. Also, the next/image does not work.

// core styles shared by all of react-notion-x (required)
import 'react-notion-x/src/styles.css'

import * as React from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
// import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import { ExtendedRecordMap } from 'notion-types'
import { getPageTitle } from 'notion-utils'
import { NotionRenderer } from 'react-notion-x'

import {CldImageProps} from "next-cloudinary"
import CldImage from './CldImage'

// import TweetEmbed from 'react-tweet-embed'

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// dynamic imports for optional components
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const Collection = dynamic(() =>
  import('react-notion-x/build/third-party/collection').then(m => m.Collection),
)

// Extend the props for your ImageComponent
interface ImageComponentProps extends CldImageProps {
  // Add any additional props here if needed
}

const ImageComponent: React.FC<ImageComponentProps> = (props) => (
  <CldImage
    {...props}
    width={2048}
    height={1600}
    alt="illustration image for doc"
    deliveryType="fetch"
    dpr="auto"
    config={{ cloud: { cloudName: 'iant1359' } }}
  />
);

 const NotionPage = ({
  recordMap,
  previewImagesEnabled,
  rootPageId,
  rootDomain,
}: {
  recordMap: ExtendedRecordMap
  previewImagesEnabled?: boolean
  rootPageId?: string
  rootDomain?: string
}) => {
  // const router = useRouter()

  // if (router.isFallback) {
  //   return <Loading />
  // }

  if (!recordMap) {
    return null
  }

  const title = getPageTitle(recordMap)

  // useful for debugging from the dev console
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const keys = Object.keys(recordMap?.block || {})
    const block = recordMap?.block?.[keys[0]]?.value
    const g = window as any
    g.recordMap = recordMap
    g.block = block
  }

  const socialDescription = 'React Notion X Demo'
  const socialImage =
    'https://react-notion-x-demo.transitivebullsh.it/social.jpg'

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        {socialDescription && (
          <>
            <meta name="description" content={socialDescription} />
            <meta property="og:description" content={socialDescription} />
            <meta name="twitter:description" content={socialDescription} />
          </>
        )}

        {socialImage ? (
          <>
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
            <meta name="twitter:image" content={socialImage} />
            <meta property="og:image" content={socialImage} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
        )}

        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
        <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
        <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@transitive_bs" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <NotionRenderer
        recordMap={recordMap}
        fullPage
        darkMode={false}
        rootDomain={rootDomain}
        rootPageId={rootPageId}
        previewImages={previewImagesEnabled}
        components={{
          // NOTE (transitive-bullshit 3/12/2023): I'm disabling next/image for this repo for now because the amount of traffic started costing me hundreds of dollars a month in Vercel image optimization costs. I'll probably re-enable it in the future if I can find a better solution.
          nextImage: ImageComponent,
          nextLink: Link,
          // Collection,
        }}

        // NOTE: custom images will only take effect if previewImages is true and
        // if the image has a valid preview image defined in recordMap.preview_images[src]
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default NotionPage

Anyone can give me a hint?
